# How to show a tooltip on a mouse click

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jtreetable

I have a `JTreeTable` and have successfully implemented a `MouseMotionListener` to show a tooltip whenever the mouse is over one of the cells. However when clicking on the cell the tooltip does not show up. I've tried several things like setting the text on the `mouseClicked` and `mouseReleased` events but that doesn't work. I found this code -

```
Action toolTipAction = treeTable.getActionMap().get("postTip");

if(toolTipAction != null){

   ActionEvent postTip = new ActionEvent(treeTable,ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "");
   toolTipAction.actionPerformed(postTip);    
}
```

to use in the `mouseReleased` method, which does make the `tooltip popup`, but it's then in the wrong position. So next i tried overriding the `getTooltipLocation` method on the `JTreeTable`, and this works fine for `mouseMoved` events but doesn't get called with the above method. Can anyone shed some light on how to do this?

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 13):

You can use the following approach to show the tooltip (there will be a slight delay). Then you can override the getToolTipLocation() method since a MouseEvent will now be generated:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ToolTipOnRelease extends JPanel
{
    public ToolTipOnRelease()
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel( "First Name:" );
        add( label );

        JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
        add( textField );

        MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                JComponent component = (JComponent)e.getSource();
                component.setToolTipText("Mouse released on: " + component.getClass().toString());

                MouseEvent phantom = new MouseEvent(
                    component,
                    MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    false);

                ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().mouseMoved(phantom);
            }
        };

        label.addMouseListener( ml );
        textField.addMouseListener( ml );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ToolTipOnRelease");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ToolTipOnRelease() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.jorphan.gui.JTreeTable extends javax.swing.JComponent
javax.swing.JComponent#setToopTipText() doesn't work?
I do realize that you want to use Action but for tooltips? I would use Action when multiple UI actions would need to share it.